# wpa_supplicant tells "No Drivers enabled"

Tags: linux, authentication, driver

I have compiled wpa_supplicant code downloaded from http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/ version is 0.7.3. I am getting No Drivers installed while trying to run the built wpa_supplicant. Am i missing anything in its compilation? Has anyone faced this error? Is there any setting to enable drivers also while compiling wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your kernel automatically load the correct module for your wireless card? If not, `modprobe` the correct module, and try again.

Also, the `wpa_supplicant(8)` page's `AVAILABLE DRIVERS` section says that only a handful of cards are supported (disappointing, but at least you could look through the list before buying a card), and that support for the drivers may or may not be compiled in. So make sure your card's driver is on the list, and make sure you've compiled `wpa_supplicant(8)` with the correct driver.

Comment: Here after compiling i am getting this message "No Drivers enabled" when trying to launch with eth1 (ie hardwired nd option as -D wired). I suppose it to be a issue in compilation option because when i tried to use the wpa_supplicant i downloaded as binary from internet, i didnot get this error. :(

Comment: Moreover my idea is to use wpa_supplicant for IEE802.1x authentication over wired lan.

Comment: @Abhi, ah, clever, never heard of using `wpa_supplicant(8)` on wired connections before. :) How did you build `wpa_supplicant`?

Comment: :) Thank you but wpa_supplicant is also applicable for wired driver. I downloaded the wpa_supplicant's source code tall bar from http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/ version is 0.7.3 and then untarred it and used the compiler (gcc) to make the Make file. One point to note here is i was not able to find a config file to change the build configuration

Comment: @Abhi, to configure the build, copy the `defconfig` file to `.config` and edit `.config` to meet your needs, then try the build again.

Comment: Loads and Loads of Thanks :) I got it up now but yet to test it... it was a configuration issue where i missed CONFIG_DRIVER_WIRED=y which is used to enable wired ethernet. And hence when i tried launching wpa_supplicant i got the error. Atleast it is running for sure 'coz in /var/run/wpa_supplicant eth1 is available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a driver to use by enabling it in .config file of wpa_supplicant before build. They will be in the form `CONFIG_DRIVER_<name>`.

`CONFIG_DRIVER_WEXT` and `CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211` are generic that suits many hardware.